# Why Do I get Xcode 1.5 not supported?

Tags: c++, xcode, cairo, xlib

I am trying to install Cairo/Xlib on macOS I couldn't get this to work

> cmake -G "Xcode" --config Debug "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ../.

```
    CMake Error:
  Xcode 1.5 not supported.


CMake Error: Could not create named generator Xcode

Generators
* Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  Xcode                        = Generate Xcode project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
```

Comment: I suppose the first bit of information to add to your question is your version of XCode. In particular, was the version correctly detected as 1.5? Another important bit of information is your version of CMake. Probably the reason you are being told that XCode 1.5 is not supported is because you have XCode 1.5 and because XCode 1.5 is not supported by your version of CMake, but that's mere guesswork without your version numbers.

Comment: Where did you get a cairo from that can be built with CMake? Cairo upstream only has an autotools based build system.

Comment: I have the same error, and Xcode 9.2 installed on MacOS 10.12.6 Sierra (it's the latest Xcode supported on that OS).

Answer (score 7):

See also this:)

https://wiki.vcmi.eu/How_to_build_VCMI_(macOS)

```
Installing Xcode
App Store -> Xcode Launch it after the installation to agree with it's license terms.

Alternatively Xcode can be downloaded from Apple Developers website. Registration is easier and every possible version is available: https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Setting Xcode version Xcode
In case you have some weird CMake errors during generation attempts such as

CMake Error: Xcode 1.5 not supported.
You might need to specify installed version of Xcode:

sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Users/admin/Downloads/Xcode.app
After that Cmake will be able to generate projects properly!
```

or just do

cmake ../
make

Answer (score 3):

After I moved Xcode to the applications folder (it was somehow installed in the download folder) this error has gone.

Answer (score 2):

from ： https://github.com/mysql-inception/inception/issues/67

sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode_10.1.app

(I have multiple versions of Xcode so that's why it's not just Xcode.app)

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error but instead of using the graphical CMake, I added the path to the CMake in the Application folder /Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/ to zshell path, then started the makefile creation from terminal. It worked.

I then use ./make and the compilation worked.

Answer (score -1):

First Google result for "cmake XCode" is https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/generator/Xcode.html which says

> This supports Xcode 3.0 and above.

So, apparently this message comes from CMake.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the original author knew it's something to do with cmake.

Comment: Since the question is tagged with "cairo" and "xlib", I did not feel so.